Using <component :is,,, /> in vue to load svg
I want to use the component tag in vue composition api, in a way that give the path to my svg file I'd be able to load it on the page.
I have this problem for a while and I think there would be an easy way to sort it out.
this is my LoadSvg.vue file:

<template>
  <component :is="svgData"/>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {IconPack, useSvgLoader} from "@/composables/useSvgLoader";
import {computed} from "vue";
import {asyncComputed} from "@vueuse/core";

const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<{
      name: string
      pack: IconPack
    }>(),{
      name: "add",
      pack: IconPack.Utility
    }
)
const svgData  = asyncComputed(async ()=>{
  return await useSvgLoader(props.name, props.pack)
})
console.log(svgData)
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>

where useSvgLoader is:
export enum IconPack {
    Utility,
    Action,
    Custom,
    Doctype,
    Standard
}

export function useSvgLoader(iconName: string, iconPack: IconPack = IconPack.Utility ){
    const name = `${iconName}.svg`
    switch (iconPack) {
        case IconPack.Utility: return import(`@/assets/icons/utility/${name}`)
        case IconPack.Action: return import(`~/assets/icons/action/${name}`)
        case IconPack.Custom: return import(`~/assets/icons/custom/${name}`)
        case IconPack.Doctype: return import(`~/assets/icons/doctype/${name}`)
        case IconPack.Standard: return import(`~/assets/icons/standard/${name}`)
    }
}


You can do it with just a few native Web Component lines: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Does this answer your question? Convert HTML to a Vue component in runtime
